# Does less loop in rhombus shape printing always faster than using more loops? Is there a way to print rhombus shape using 1 loop?

Tags: c, loops

I wanted to print a rhombus shape with only 1 loop. The furthest I have gone is using 2 for loops.

The result shape is as follows:
[rhombus shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnkGa.png)

```
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
*       *
 *     *
  *   *
   * *
    *
```

The code for using 3 loops is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int i, j;
  int columns = 4;
  for(i = 0; i < columns; i++){
    for(j = 0; j <= (columns-1) - i;j++){
      printf(" ");
    }
    for(j = 0;j<=2*i;j++){
      if(i == 0||j == 0||j == 2*i){
        printf("*");
      }else{
        printf(" ");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  for(i = columns; i >= 0; i--){
    for(j = 0; j <= (columns-1) - i;j++){
      printf(" ");
    }
    for(j = 0;j<=2*i;j++){
      if(i == 0||j == 0||j == 2*i){
        printf("*");
      }else{
        printf(" ");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
int main() {
  int i, j;
  int columns = 4;
  for(i = 0; i < columns; i++){
    for(j = 0;j<=(2*i+(columns) - i);j++){
      if(j==columns/2+(columns/2-i)||(j == (2*i+(columns) - i))){
        printf("*");
      }else{
        printf(" ");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
   for(i = columns; i >=0; i--){
    for(j = 0;j<=(2*i+(columns) - i);j++){
      if(j==columns/2+(columns/2-i)||(j == (2*i+(columns) - i))){
        printf("*");
      }else{
        printf(" ");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Does less loop in rhombus shape printing always faster than using more loops?
2. Is there a way to print rhombus shape using 1 loop? Without using predefined functions like string().

Sorry for my English, looking forward to hearing from you guys.

Comment: Yes, there is a better way. Simply use puts

Comment: Less loop, even a single loop is possible, but if it always checks the column & row to decide on printing space instead of a star, then it actually consumes more CPU instruction (don't really matter time-wise since they're exceedingly simple and the compiler & CPU can optimize them), Only printing the stars with puts and moving to the next line immediately should be faster (though again, the real runtime will be negligble)

Comment: Why not just use `printf` padding specifier on an empty string (`%*s`).  Something like this: https://ideone.com/8C0eNp ..  or just print the `*` itself with padding: https://ideone.com/pSljv8

Comment: Sequential loops are just fine. Nested loops are where you get into performance trouble.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Your answers are amazing, they really helped!

Answer (score 3):

Let's address the questions in order...

> 1. Does less loop in rhombus shape printing always faster than using more loops?

Firstly, you should not be concerned about *speed* in a program like this.  Except maybe if you are trying to print a HUGE rhombus or this is intended to run on a small battery-operated embedded device requiring low power consumption.

I don't think you're doing any of these.

The answer really is no: both your approaches are doing roughly the same amount of looping.  They're not very efficient, because they are calling a fairly expensive function once for each character output.

More importantly, the code is **overly complicated, unclear and difficult to read**.  You should be focusing here, instead of worrying about trivial performance considerations.

> 2. Is there a way to print rhombus shape using 1 loop? Without using predefined functions like string().

Yes, I posted an example in the comments where you can just use a specifier in the `printf` call to output some amount of padding.  Internally, that does basically the same thing as your own loops, but it makes shorter, clearer code and fewer `printf` calls.

Here, you just work out how many spaces are required before the `*` and then how many after it.  You can then ask `printf` to output the string `"*"` padded with some number of spaces.  Use `%*s` to indicate there are two parameters: the total width of the string, and the string itself.  The width will be the number of spaces you want, plus 1 for the actual string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
 
int main(void)
{
    const int N = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i <= N*2; i++)
    {
        int space_before = abs(N - i);
        int space_after = 2 * (N - space_before ) - 1;

        if (space_after > 0)
            printf("%*s%*s\n", space_before + 1, "*", space_after + 1, "*");
        else
            printf("%*s\n", space_before + 1, "*");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, this is easier to understand, but it's still a bit clunky.  How about we move it into a function, and then get rid of the branching in the loop.  All the loop iterations output two stars except the first and last ones which are simpler.  So, here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void display_rhombus(int size)
{
    if (size > 0)
    {
        printf("%*s\n", size + 1, "*");
        for (int i = 1; i < size*2; i++)
        {
            int space_before = abs(size - i);
            int space_after = 2 * (size - space_before ) - 1;
            printf("%*s%*s\n", space_before + 1, "*", space_after + 1, "*");
        }
    }
    printf("%*s\n", size + 1, "*");
}

int main(void)
{
    display_rhombus(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, you have a function with a name that describes what it does, has simple-to-understand code, and is re-usable.  You can call it many times to draw whatever sizes of rhombus you want.

```
int main(void)
{
    for (int size = 0; size < 10; size++)
    {
        display_rhombus(size);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, I should also mention that it's possible to output a rhombus with *no* loops, using a technique called recursion.  I will leave that as a learning exercise for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! very detailed answer and very coherent and clear explanation.

Comment: Hi paddy, I have made the program with recursion. If you have time, could you please have a look? How can I improve this piece of code?https://ideone.com/zDR0YE

Comment: Sure, well it does suffer the problem that it's hard-coded to produce a rhombus of size 4, and seems to be using recursion only to control a loop variable.  You should try to think of recursion as breaking a problem down into a smaller problem.  On a stylistic note, watch your indentation, ask yourself what `printf("");` does, and choose appropriate function names.  Decide what language you are using.  You seem to be using a mixture of C and C++.  Feel free to analyze the recursive solution I made yesterday to demonstrate: https://ideone.com/RhVx1A

Answer (score 0):

Well, apart from paddy's excellent answer, here's another one:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

void printStar(int size) {
    int j = size / 2;
    int i = size % 2 == 0 ? j - 1 : j;
    bool flag = false;
    while (i <= j) {
        std::vector<char> vec(size, ' ');
        vec.at(i) = '*';
        vec.at(j) = '*';
        std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char> {std::cout});
        std::cout << "\n";
        if (!flag) {
            i--;
            j++;
        }
        else {
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        if (i == -1) {
            flag = true;
            i += 2;
            j -= 2;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    printStar(5);
    return 0;
}
```